# CSS Contains Selector with a NOT qualifier?

Tags: css, selenium

I'm using the following in some selenium code:

```
WaitForElement(By.CssSelector("#document-count:contains(<number greater than 0>)"));
```

Specifying the `number greater than 0` is where I'm stuck.  Is there any way to use only css to check and see if an element's innertext has something other than 0?

Comment: This isn't going to work any way. There is no `contains` selector in CSS. If you want to do text-based searching, you'll have to use XPath.

Comment: @Arran - do you have an example of using Xpath to select an element based on ID and InnerText?

Comment: `//[@id='document-count'][not(contains(text(), '0'))]`... hideous.. I know.  I think that's your xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:contains` was deprecated in CSS3.  Since WebDriver ties directly into the browser, it's unable to use that pseudo-class.

> Is there any way to use only css to check and see if an element's innertext has something other than 0?

Unfortunately not.  CSS really screwed Selenium users over with their deprecation of both `:contains` and `:nth`

As Arran said, you can use xpath, or - if you are willing to experiment with C# and CSS together *(not just css as you state)* then you can come up with something to loop x amount of times checking the text.

Answer (score 2):

[**Per Chris Coyier at CSS Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/):

> ## Deprecated
>
> **:contains()** - As far as I know, this is gone. The current
> CSS3 spec has removed it. I don't know the story, let me know if you
> do. At a glance, it looks ridiculously useful (being able to select
> objects based on the textual content they contain). It may be because
> of problems, or having content in selectors being undesirable. My
> preference would be to have it select by elements rather than text,
> like p:contains(img), but alas, no such luck.

---

That said, if you were to set the value properties, you may be able to use `:not([value="0"])`:

[**See jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M6Ljm/)

---

### HTML

```
<div id="doc">
    <input type="text" value="0" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" value="1" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" value="2" />
</div>
```

---

### CSS

```
#doc input[value="0"]
{
    background: red;
}

#doc input:not([value="0"])
{
    background: green;
}
```

---

### Result

[image: jsFiddle Result]